# I believe I need a small increase in code quality in the code I have written for Double Linked List

Tags: c++

I know only Java and am trying to learn C++ . I having some difficulty with pointers . Currently I am coding a small program to append a node to the front of the Doubly Linked List. Although the code is working I am not that happy with some parts of it. I believe although I am trying to code in C++ my code is ending somewhat looking like a fusion of C++ and Java. Can someone suggest some improvements

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class DLNode{
    int data;
    DLNode *left;
    DLNode *right;
public:
    DLNode(int d);
    int getData() const;
    DLNode * create(int d);//Supposedly something I have coded to get past the error of temporary address
    DLNode * getPreviousNode() const;
    DLNode * getNextNode() const;
    void setNextNode(DLNode * r);
    void setPreviousNode(DLNode * l);
};

DLNode::DLNode(int d){
    data=d;
    left=NULL;
    right=NULL;
}
DLNode * DLNode:: create(int d){
    DLNode * newNode=new DLNode(d);
    return newNode;
}

int DLNode:: getData() const{
    return data;
}

DLNode * DLNode:: getPreviousNode() const{
    return left;
}

DLNode * DLNode::getNextNode() const{
    return right;
}

void DLNode::setNextNode(DLNode * r){
    right=r;
}

void DLNode::setPreviousNode(DLNode * l){
    left=l;
}


class DoubleLinkedListImplementation{
private:
    DLNode * head;
public:
    DLNode * getHead(){
        return head;
    }
    DoubleLinkedListImplementation();
    void appendToBeginningOfList(int data);
    void printListContents();
};

DoubleLinkedListImplementation::DoubleLinkedListImplementation(){
    head=NULL;
}

void DoubleLinkedListImplementation::printListContents(){
    const DLNode * movingPointer=head;
    while(movingPointer!=NULL){
         cout<<movingPointer->getData()<<endl;
         movingPointer=movingPointer->getNextNode();
    }
}



void DoubleLinkedListImplementation::appendToBeginningOfList(int data){
     DLNode object=DLNode(0);//This is where the problem is
      DLNode *node=object.create(data);// I don't like these two lines
      if(head==NULL){
          head=node;
      }
      else{
          node->setNextNode(head);
          head->setPreviousNode(node);
          head=node;
      }
}

int main(){
   DoubleLinkedListImplementation doubleImplemenation=DoubleLinkedListImplementation();
   doubleImplemenation.appendToBeginningOfList(2);
   doubleImplemenation.appendToBeginningOfList(3);
   doubleImplemenation.appendToBeginningOfList(50);
   doubleImplemenation.printListContents();
}
```

Comment: Post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: Thanks my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two alternatives to node creation:

1. use of create method but you have to make it static. You don;t have to instantiate other object in order to call 'create' method. That way you use sort of factory method pattern.

   class DLNode{
       ...
        static DLNode * create(int d);
       ...
       }

   ```
   void DoubleLinkedListImplementation::appendToBeginningOfList(int data)
   {
         DLNode *node=DLNode::create(data);
         if(head==NULL){
             head=node;
         }
         else{
             node->setNextNode(head);
             head->setPreviousNode(node);
             head=node;
         }
   }
   ```
2. use directly the new operator to create your node

   ```
   void DoubleLinkedListImplementation::appendToBeginningOfList(int data)
   {
         DLNode *node= new DLNode(data);
         if(head==NULL){
             head=node;
         }
         else{
             node->setNextNode(head);
             head->setPreviousNode(node);
             head=node;
         }
   }
   ```